# Gradle Sync Failed - MissingPropertyException after upgrade to gradle 5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Just updated to `Android Studio 3.3 RC 2` & `gradle tools to 5.1`, it started to give the following **error**,

```
No such property: dir for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: dir for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
```

Any idea what's the solution to this?

I'm using
`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha08`

Comment: Are you using Jacoco? If that's the case, you should update the plugin to 0.1.4. See https://github.com/arturdm/jacoco-android-gradle-plugin/issues/54

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The issue with me was related to Jacoco android plugin version 0.1.3
I solved the issue by updating to 0.1.4 and now the issue is solved.

Comment: Awesome works @melad

The team from `gradle` also stated here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8243#issuecomment-454902781

And here's from `jacoco-android-gradle-plugin` team issue history:
https://github.com/arturdm/jacoco-android-gradle-plugin/issues/54#issuecomment-467238359

Answer (score 3):

In my case this happened when I upgraded Android Studio to gradle 4.1.0-beta01

The problem was with fabric plugin . I had to replace fabric plugin with `firebase-crashlytics-gradle` plugin

Project build.gradle

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-beta01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.2.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
//        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'   replaced with below
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0"

    }
```

Applevel build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'   //use this instead of fabric

 
dependencies {
 
//    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'  replace with below
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was the jacoco android plugin integration. Fixed it by removing code related to its integration in the project build.gradle file. Hopes this helps!.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by downgrading gradle to 4.10.3 and com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-rc02

Comment: not a fix, but a temporal workaround... Here is correct answer that should be upvoted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55811855/304270